# SAS Enterprise Guide with VBScript. Looping through SAS programs get stuck

Tags: vbscript, sas

I'm facing a random problem. When executing SAS programs with VBScript and the SASEGObjectModel.Application.7.1, looping through CodeCollection get stuck sometimes, even if the program execution was succeeded (the final data bases are correctly created in our server). The script simple doesn't go to the next program of CodeCollection (the prompt executing the script still open... ad infinitum). The SAS program It happens is random, also the frequency. I'm going with something like this:

```
Dim oSasApp

Set oSasApp = CreateObject("SASEGObjectModel.Application.7.1")
oSasApp.SetActiveProfile("some-profile")

Dim oSasProj
Set oSasProj = oSasApp.Open("some-project.egp", "")

Dim oProgramList
Set oProgramList = oSasProj.CodeCollection

Dim programOrder
Set programOrder = ...here I assign the SAS programs order array reading from a .txt...

For Each program in programOrder
       For Each sasProgram in oProgramList
              If sasProgram.Name = program Then
                     sasProgram.Run
                     sasProgram.Log.SaveAs "some-folder/" & sasProgram.Name & ".txt"
              End If
       Next
Next

oSasProj.Close
oSasApp.Quit
```

The problem is not the Log saving, as the log txt file of the stucked program is also correctly created.

Any idea? Maybe problems in our SAS server? Should I declare some kind of options?

SAS Guide version: 7.15
Windows: 10

Tks

Comment: You will want to look into the SAS server logs.  It's possible some connections were refused or dropped during a heavy influx of run requests, or the run dispatcher for the connection is hung on some unclosed or locked resource.  If you are running local SAS sessions, use Windows resource monitor for expected SAS sessions that might be 'hung'.  Other good local troubleshoot tools are Sysinternals Process Monitor and Process Explorer

Comment: You could also try adding in a delay after each program has run to ensure it's not the frequency of requests causing the issue.

Comment: That's good info.

Just found out something that changes erverything and makes the problem simpler: if I press enter on prompt the script flows again. So it is waiting for my input. Can't understand why as I did't code anything for that in the .vbs file. Must be something with SAS Enterprise Guide. The data bases I'm manipulating are preatty big, the main programs takes something like 7 hours to run. I'm thinking if SAS Guide is asking anything to goes on. Maybe something related to the data size? The log? Results? Any idea what could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... for people facing the same problem. As I commented above, if I press enter on prompt the script flows again. So it is waiting for my input, for reasons I can't tell. I did 2 things to get around it. Not sure if all of them are necessary or if only one solves it, but here it goes:

First, by VBScript I turned off a list of generations and I applied a delay after the SAS program runs:

```vb
For Each program in programOrder
       For Each sasProgram i oProgramList
              If sasProgram.Name = program Then
                     sasProgram.GenSasReport = False
                     sasProgram.GenHTML = False
                     sasProgram.GenListing = False
                     sasProgram.GenPDF = False
                     sasProgram.GenRTF = False
                     sasProgram.Run
                     WScript.Sleep(2000)
                     sasProgram.Log.SaveAs "some-folder/" & sasProgram.Name & ".txt"
              End If
       Next
Next
```

Them, in my batch file, wich I use to call the VBScript with the "cscript" command, I set it to apply "y" to every single message the VBScript could ask:

```
cd ./script-folder
echo y | cscript script-file-name.vbs
```

And that is it.